# Facing issues while creating a shell script which satisfies conditions.

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to write a shell script which will help me to **copy files from one directory to another satisfying some conditions.**

- It should first check if there is any directory with the name of the
  file (yes, i said directory ) in the destination path. And if yes, then it should check whether,
  the directory is having any files in it. If the condition is true, move
  on to the next file. Else delete the directory and copy the file.
- If the first condition is false (checking the file name with directory
  name), copying should be done.

**I succeed in truncating the extension (.TIF in this case) and storing the file names into a variable. 
Currently i am facing an issue with comparing this variable with the folders in destination path.**

Might be an easy case for majority of you guys, i am a newbie and iam
   facing issues with the proper shell scripting.

Comment: If you're succeeding in some parts of the problem, factor them out of the question -- ask only, specifically, about what you're having trouble with. Also, show what you're trying and how it's failing. In an ideal world, a question will have a [minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with enough code to show how the failing parts fail, and let someone else run them to see the failure themselves.

Comment: ...in this case, a minimal, verifiable example might actually set up your directory structure -- for instance: `mkdir -p in out/empty out/nonempty; touch in/empty.tif in/nonempty.tif out/nonempty/example`, and then showing what the contents of these directories should be *after* your script is run.